# How does this divide equation for polynomials make sense?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, fast-fourier-transform

I'm trying to understand the Fast Fourier Transform. On several articles I read, I found this formula for dividing polynomials into even and odd terms ([example](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fft.html)).

Given $ A(x)=a_0x^0+a_1x^1+⋯+a_{n−1} x^{n−1} $

When divided into even and odd terms,

$$
A(x)=A_0(x^2)+xA_1(x^2)
$$

My question is, how did the $x^2$ come to be? Obviously, both versions give different answers when evaluated. So, what does it really mean?

I'm not very math savvy. So, please avoid as much jargon as possible :)

Comment: You should include in your question how $A_0(x)$ and $A_1(x)$ are defined.

Comment: Even powers of $x$ are integer powers of $x^2$, and odd powers of $x$ are $x$ times an even power of $x$.

Comment: All this ultimately is, is a decomposition of $A$ into terms with odd exponent and even exponent.

Comment: @dxiv You mean, raise $x^2$ to the power of index of each coefficient?

Comment: @ManuSoman That depends on which index you have in mind. But for a simple example $A(x)=x^3+2x^2+3x+4=(2x^2+4)+ x \cdot (x^2+3)=A_0(x^2)+x\cdot A_1(x^2)$ where $A_0(x)=2x+4$ and $A_1(x)=x+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given
\begin{aligned}
A(x)&=a_0x^0+a_1x^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
A_0(x)&=a_0x^0+a_2x^1+\cdots+a_{n-2}x^{(n/2)-1}\\
A_1(x)&=a_1x^0+a_3x^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{(n/2)-1}\\
\end{aligned}

We get
\begin{aligned}
A_0(x^2) &=a_0(x^2)^0+a_2(x^2)^1+\cdots+a_{n-2}(x^2)^{(n/2)-1}\\
&=a_0x^0+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}\\
\end{aligned}

Similarly,
\begin{aligned}
xA_1(x^2) &=x\left(a_1(x^2)^0+a_3(x^2)^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}(x^2)^{(n/2)-1}\right)\\
&=x\left(a_1x^0+a_3x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}\right)\\
&=a_1x^1+a_3x^3+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
\end{aligned}

Thus, $A(x)=A_0(x^2)+xA_1(x^2)$